# Spacy Matcher: TypeError: an integer is required

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I'm trying to create a phrase matcher with spacy but I keep getting an error that says: TypeError: an integer is required. My 'classes' are the rows from a column I selected from my database. I don't understand why an integer is required since looking at the documentation they seem to be doing the same thing I am doing but whenever I try to run the code I get an error in my matcher.add.
Any idea would be appreciated. This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import PhraseMatcher
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize, sent_tokenize
import nltk

data = pd.read_csv('C:/woclorev.csv')

class_name = data['Class Name'].drop_duplicates()
class_name_str = class_name.tolist()

reviews = data['Reviewtext'].astype(str)
token_rev = reviews.apply(word_tokenize)

#PhraseMatcher object
matcher = PhraseMatcher(nlp.vocab, attr='LOWER')
matcher.add('Classes', None, *class_name_str)
matches = matcher(token_rev)
```

This is the full error message:
File "", line 1, in  File "phrasematcher.pyx", line 209, in spacy.matcher.phrasematcher.PhraseMatcher.add
TypeError: an integer is required

Comment: can you put the full error message?

Comment: also, make sure to always provide a sample of the data you're working with, if possible. it is often critical to solving the problem.

Comment: I added the full error message

Answer (score 1):

From [the docs](https://spacy.io/api/phrasematcher)

> The PhraseMatcher lets you efficiently match large terminology lists. While the Matcher lets you match sequences based on lists of token descriptions, *the PhraseMatcher accepts match patterns in the form of Doc objects.*

Without being able to see what word_tokenize is (I'm assuming nltk implementation?) it's hard to say for sure, but if that function is *not returning spaCy Doc objects, the matcher will likely raise an exception*

Comment: Yes, I added the importing of the package to the code.

Comment: Excellent, then that is in fact the cause of your problem. `token_rev = reviews.apply(word_tokenize)` means that `token_rev` is going to be a list of lists, where each sub-list is the tokenized string, not a list of spaCy Doc object's. For each line of text (each element in `token_rev`) you need to join the list of strings together, and then make them into Doc's again, by processing with nlp. Here's an example of doing this on the first line: `doc = nlp(' '.join(token_rev[0]))`

Comment: Oh that makes sense, but I get the error when I run this: matcher.add('Classes', None, *class_name_str). I tried doing what you said to my class_name_str but it still says the same thing... My class_name_str is formed with the rows of a column.. Do you know what I can do to solve it? Thank you already for the help! My last part of the code does give me another error as well: File "phrasematcher.pyx", line 240, in spacy.matcher.phrasematcher.PhraseMatcher.__call__
TypeError: Cannot convert Series to spacy.tokens.doc.Doc and even doing what you said seems not to change it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your matcher is not receiving a list of doc objects, but a list of strings.

The inputs for the function matcher.add() are:

1. A custom ID for your matcher;
2. Optional parameter for callable function;
3. A pattern list.

You can convert the list of phrases into a doc object through make_doc() method. It is faster and saves time.

## Terms to match

```
terms_list = ['Bruce Wayne', 'Tony Stark', 'Batman', 'Harry Potter', 'Severus Snape']
```

## Make a list of docs

```
patterns = [nlp.make_doc(text) for text in terms_list]
```

## Add to the macher

```
matcher.add("phrase_matcher", None, *patterns)
```

Reference: https://www.machinelearningplus.com/spacy-tutorial-nlp/

Comment: Do you know how to append these matches to the doc.ents ? I raised a question for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69785216/appending-new-entities-in-doc-ents-in-spacy3-fails It would be great if you can have a look at it.