# Appending new entities in doc.ents in Spacy3 fails

Tags: nlp, spacy, spacy-3

I'm adding a custom component in the `nlp` pipeline in Spacy. Below are the steps that I follow.

1. create a matcher to pick the car names
2. define the custom component that uses this matcher and appends the matches to the existing `doc.ents`.

This final appending is what fails, despite supplying span object types.

```
# Matcher info
cars = ['honda', 'toyota', 'yamaha', 'mazda', 'range rover', 'mercedes']
matcher = PhraseMatcher(nlp.vocab)
patterns = list(nlp.pipe(cars))
matcher.add('acar?', None, *patterns)

# Define component
@Language.component('car_check')
def car_component(doc, name='isacar?'):
    cars =[Span(doc,start, end, label='CAR')
           for match_id, start, end in matcher(doc)]
    doc.ents = list(doc.ents) + [cars]
    return doc

nlp.add_pipe('car_check',after='ner')

doc=nlp("fascinated by european cars like range rover & mercedes, love japanese cars like toyota and nissan ")
```

I get the following error in the final step.

```
---->    doc.ents = list(doc.ents) + [cars]
TypeError: an integer is required
```

Why does this fail ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you're getting that exact error, but the issue is that you are wrapping `cars` in a list but it's already a list. Try this:

```
doc.ents = list(doc.ents) + cars
```

Also note it won't work if you have overlapping entities.

Have you seen the [EntityRuler](https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching#entityruler)? You're basically doing the same thing, so it'd probably be easier to use it directly.

Comment: The reason was due to overlapping entities. Wrapping cars in list is not the issue. You can correct your answer, so that i can mark this as answered.